# Simple CMS solution to add 3 lines of HTML?

Tags: html, content-management-system, image-gallery

I've made a one-pager for a friend's photography portfolio, and the content's basically this:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href="imageThatOpensInFancyBox">
   <img thumbnail>
  </a>
  <div>title for thumbnail rollover</div>
 </li>
 ...
</ul>
```

I want him to be able to just add pictures as time goes (basically add more li's to the ul), without him coding anything. Any suggestions ? Drupal or something might be a little overkill I think.

Thanks !

Comment: How will he upload images? Can he resize them himself and/or use FTP to UL?

Comment: Why not use a hosted gallery such as picasa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to host the images on http://imgur.com and create a gallery. You can then embed the gallery of images to the website. When you upload new images, they will automatically be added.

Comment: Yes, a simple solution. There are plenty of such web services that hosts image galleries, such as Flickr or other where you can dynamically fetch your images from...

Comment: Yes, Flickr and similar sites work too. Imgur was just the one that came to mind.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, most CMS would be an overkill. This would depend on your backend programming skills, The easiest way would be to create a simple admin page that lets the user upload/delete images. And the frontend loops through all the items that has been uploaded so far and have it wrapped around your html.

Another solution would be to use a service like Flickr where the user uploads an image with a specific tag like "portfolio" and you use their API to loop through all the items and wrap it with the html that you have shown above.